# having trouble running node js on server

Tags: node.js, api, ubuntu, server

I've implemented a node.js script that uses several APIs to download an image from a website, save it to my hard drive, then upload that image to an Instagram account

the apis are:

unsplash
instagram-private-api
image-downloader

I've gotten the java script to execute successfully on my local windows machine through the command line.

I'm currently running an Ubuntu 16.04 server off of vultr. I've tried following plenty of online tutorials but none seem to work for me.

when i get the javascript file on the server, and try to run it through the command lines I get the error

```
root@insta-bot:~/instagram/instagrambot/VintageCars/JS Scripts# nodejs upld_Cars                                                                                        .js
/root/instagram/instagrambot/VintageCars/JS Scripts/upld_Cars.js:8
  let data = '';
  ^^^

SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet sup                                                                                        ported outside strict mode
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:966:3
```

here is my javascript code:

```
//Download
const https = require('https');
const download = require('image-downloader')

 var search ='sexy-car'
https.get('NOTREALSEARCHCRITERIA, (resp) => {
  let data = '';

  // A chunk of data has been recieved.
  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.

  resp.on('end', () => {
    photoUrl = JSON.parse(data).urls.custom;
    console.log(photoUrl);
    // Download to a directory and save with the original filename
const options = {
  url: photoUrl,
  dest: 'C:/Users/USER/Desktop/instagrambot/VintageCars/unsplash_Vintage_Car_dwnld/image.jpg' // Save to /path/to/dest/image.jpg
}

download.image(options)
  .then(({ filename, image }) => {
    console.log('File saved to', filename)
  }).catch((err) => {
    throw err
  })
  });

}).on("error", (err) => {
  console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});


// Upload
var Client = require('instagram-private-api').V1;
var device = new Client.Device('FAKEDEVICE');
var storage = new Client.CookieFileStorage(__dirname + '/cookies/carVintagePage.json');

var username = 'NOTREALUSERNAME';
var pass = 'NOTREALPASS'

var Approved_Hashtags = ['#Beautiful ', '#Vintage ', '#Car ', '#Carstagram ', '#OnlyAutomobiles ',
                         '#OldStyle ' , '#Classic ', '#OldCars ', '#OldAutos ', '#ClassicCars ', 
                         '#CarPorn ', '#VintageCar ', '#Stunning ', '#Amazing '];

var caption = getCaption(Approved_Hashtags);

var pathOrStream = 'C:/Users/USER/Desktop/instagrambot/VintageCars/unsplash_Vintage_Car_dwnld/image.jpg';

Client.Session.create(device, storage, username, pass)
.then(function(session){
  return [Client.Upload.photo(session, pathOrStream), session]
})
.spread(function(upload, session) {
  return Client.Media.configurePhoto(session, upload.params.uploadId, caption)
})
.then(function(medium) {
  console.log(medium)
})

//////////////////////function////////////////////////////////

function getCaption(arr) {
    n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7) + 3  
    var result = new Array(n),
        len = arr.length,
        taken = new Array(len);
    while (n--) {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * len);
        result[n] = arr[x in taken ? taken[x] : x];
        taken[x] = --len;
    }

    var caption = '';
    for(var tag of result)
        caption+= tag;

    return caption;
}
```

I've gotten the script to work locally flawlessly. but on the server i receive the above error. I've installed node, and all the APIs using npm install.

I'm not sure why i get this error. any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The error you get `Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet sup` makes it sound like when it runs on vultr that it's running an older version of node.js that doens't yet support `let` and `const`.  On vultr, when you run `node -v`, what does it report?

Comment: Yes you should probably update your node version and it should be fine

Comment: when i type:  nodejs -v
i get: v4.2.6

Answer (score 0):

You need to update nodeJS.
upgrade node using the typical instructions , if that doesn't work :

```
sudo npm install -g npm
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

find out where your node is located by running `which node`

sudo ln -sf /usr/local/n/versions/node/`<VERSION>`/bin/node /usr/bin/node

Use whatever the highest version is in place of "`<VERSION>`" from your install options in /usr/local/n/versions/node

Comment: i ended up using this :curl -sL https:/                                                                                   /deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -